# Why does the ADC require 3 wires instead of 2?

Tags: adc

I'm very confused about ADC. I do apologize if these questions sound silly. I use ATMEGA328P for ADC.

1. Why is the negative terminal required for ADC to take measurements, if the ADC pin is already negative by itself?
2. Why does the ADC only take measurements when resistance is present between the ground and the ADC input pin? If I remove the 1k resistor, then measurements no longer work, why doesn't ADC pick this up, unless a resistor is present?

[image]

3. If I take the VCC and GND wire between my fingers in separate hands, and let the ADC wire 'float', I get a wave:
   (no photo-cell, just bare wires, GND in my left hand VCC in my right hand and ADC input floating in the air)
   [image]

What is this wave representing? If I don't hold the VCC and GND, then the ADCH is just showing random output, so the wave doesn't occur by itself. My vref is set to AREF of 4v.

If I connect the ADC to an aluminium jar, I see what appears to be square wave, is that possible that I'm picking up some kind of signal from  random device, like for example wifi chip? or not without op-amp?

Comment: Pay attention to your timebase. Is it just possible that your waveform is 60 Hz? Does that remind you of anything?

Comment: And if it is not 60Hz, it might be 50Hz.

Comment: Without the resistor "technically the voltage does change between the 5V and A0 connection based on photocell value" - no it doesn't! Measure it with a multimeter.

Comment: And is that 50/60 Hz in turn from the photocell being shined on by fluorescent light or just some floating ground in your setup?

Comment: @pcj50 sorry, I think we might misunderstood each other. if you type "Light-Dependent Resistor (LDR) Demo" in youtube, the first video  shows that voltage changes between the positive and negative terminals. I don't understand then why can't ADC pick this up if connected directly to GND (without any resistor between ADC input and GND)

Comment: @winny photo cell is not in the picture, I just have 3 bare wires - VCC, GND and ADC input. And the wave only occurs when I hold the VCC and GND in my hands, I never seen it in other conditions/setup.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I mean 60hz is heartbeat, but it sure looks strange on the screen. I'm running i2c on 100hz, but I don't see the relation, could you please explain?

Comment: So why is there a photocell in your schematic? Bare wires? Connected where? Draw a circuit diagram of the actual circuit!

Comment: @winny questions 2 and 3 are separate. Bare wires as I stated twice before - in my left and right hand. For question #2, that's the complete schematic.

Comment: No it isn't! How is your oscilloscope grounded and powered? From where is 5 V powered and grounded? Draw the complete circuit. Where is the ADC? What ADC are you using? Where is Vref and how it it generated?

Comment: @0x29a we have URLs for a reason! I see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4QQuCMG14w which does not show a voltage change, the meter is in Ohm mode.

Comment: @winny it's not an oscilloscope, it's atmega328 microcontroller with oled connected to it and I'm using it's analog input to do this and simply display the ADCH value on the screen. I have connected the VCC (4v) into the AREF pin so vref is 4v which comes from bench power supply.

Comment: @pjc50 sorry, I thought it's against the rules to post them, since they 'expire'. But still, if only resistance change, why doesn't the ADC see this resistance, unless there's additional resistor between GND and ADC input pin?

Comment: Better, but still unclear with no schematic. I vote to close since it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @winny no point on closing, Ken already gave the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: "I mean 60hz is heartbeat, " Oh, really? 60 beats per second? You should see a doctor.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I got drug issues

Comment: Next time, one question per question please.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Djima, are you seriously suggesting to post 3 related questions as 3 separate posts? All my questions were related to 'WHY DOES ADC USE 3 WIRES". btw, thanks for the down votes, not the first time you do this shit, a good way on keeping someone, who is seeking for an answer to the same question I have, from not finding it. And because of these down voters, I have ignored many questions that had the right answer because of this. What you're doing is illogical and down vote should require an explanation. If it wasn't you, my apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The photocell and 1K form a voltage divider, creating a voltage depending on the light. You'll get 5V * 1K / (R+1K) as the voltage on A0. With just the photocell, A0 will be pulled up to 5V so that's no use.

With the wires loose, you're picking up stray AC signals - the wires act as an antenna.

Comment: "voltage divider" - thank explains everything, thank you so much!! Do you think you could tell me where the sin wave is coming from when I hold the vcc and gnd wires? I can never reproduce it unless I take the power supply vcc and gnd and hold them with my hands.

Comment: @0x29a The sine wave is 60 Hz (or 50 Hz if you're in Europe) emissions from your power lines.

Comment: Your body is picking up "hum" from the power mains. This is always present virtually everywhere inside buildings that are wired with power.  But most gear is designed to be NOT sensitive to this "noise".  What you are seeing is completely expected, normal and predictable.  If you look at the FREQUENCY of your signal you will find that it is almost certainly the utility power frequency (50Hz or 60Hz depending on where you are).

Comment: @RichardCrowley that's very interesting, thank you very much for explaining!